# Remove underline from Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I'm trying to create a Table of Contents but I am having some trouble getting it to look how I want.

At the moment I have the section headings underlined in the document and because of this when the table of contents is generated it underlines all the section headings. So my question is, is there a way to remove the unwanted underlines from the table of contents and keep them in the document.

My `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}   % color links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %color for links
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} % line in footer 
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\begin{flushleft}\large
name\newline title\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright} \thepage\end{flushright}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage

\section{\underline{The Client}}
\subsection{Sub section 1}

\section{\underline{Scope}}
\subsection{Sub Section 2}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, that will help immensely. However, are all those packages needed to reproduce the problem?  Since the problem occurs if you remove all those packages that are not related to the TOC, or the underlined section headings. I might perhaps leave `hyperref` and the associated code as that does have an effect on the TOC (but problem occurs with or without it).

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, I need all those packages and I would like to keep the typerref package functionality as im planning on doing my final year thesis in latex.

Comment: Yes I know you need those packages, but are they related to this specific problem? They certainly don't appear to be as I get identical results without them.

Comment: @PeterGrill I am new to Latex so I'm not sure. I have noticed that some commands dont work when certain packages are used but im not getting an errors so I presume the packages are not the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Your minimal example produces a ToC that looks like this (in code form):

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\relax $\@@underline {\hbox {The Client}}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax }{2}{section.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Sub section 1}{2}{subsection.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}\relax $\@@underline {\hbox {Scope}}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax }{2}{section.2}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1}Sub Section 2}{2}{subsection.2.1}
```

Note that each of the `\contentsline` entries for a `\section` contains `\@@underline`. A crude solution would be to redefine `\@@underline` to be a "no-op" (do nothing) when processing `\tableofcontents`:

```
{\makeatletter
\def\@@underline#1{#1}
\tableofcontents
\makeatother}
```

[image]

---

If only some of your sections require this "special treatment", then manual underlining is most likely the way to go, together with the correction above, or by using the optional argument for sections:

```
\section[The Client]{\underline{The Client}}
```

However, for more far-reaching or consistent requirement across your entire document, consider using a package dedicated to sectional titles. For example, [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) provides an example in its [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/sectsty.pdf) doing exactly this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}% http://ctan.org/pkg/secsty
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ulem
\usepackage{xcolor,hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xcolor,hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %color for links
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\sectionfont{\underline}

\section{The Client}
\subsection{Sub section 1}

\section{Scope}
\subsection{Sub Section 2}

\end{document}
```

Note the difference in the underlining between the choice of `sectsty` and that of a manual underline.